# How reuse connection for Service Bus Relay REST Service

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

We are exposing the REST service via Azure Service Bus. I've seen couple of sample for connection reuse of SOAP Services with ChannelFactory.

However I've not come across how to re-use connection for Azure Service Bus Relay REST Service.  Could someone please share code/idea on how it's possible to reuse connection for Azure Service Bus Relay REST service?

Thanks.

Comment: What connection are you referring to? HTTP? TCP? What code would you like to re-use the connection over?

Comment: We are using HTTP connection, please

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the channels that you create with the `ChannelFactory`

Comment: What binding type are you using on the service?